# Validation for display message "no result found"

Tags: php

I have a PHP search. Currently, when no results are displayed the script shows and error. How can I make it display a message like "No Results found" when nothing is returned?

```
<?php
include("incls/connector.php"); 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$_POST[compName]'");

while($rowval = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $complainer = $rowval['username'];
        $department = $rowval['department'];
        $phonenumber = $rowval['phone_number'];
    }
        else
    {
        echo 'No Results were found';
    }

    mysql_close()
?>
```

Comment: i hope this is typo: `mysql_close()` missing semi colon

Comment: There is no if statement condition and you are using else.

Comment: 1) stop using deprecated extension,2) print_r($_POST), 3) ELSE must need his brother `IF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WARNING** STOP USING mysql_* use mysqli_* or PDO 
Your code is wrong, you need an `if` to use `else`

```
include("incls/connector.php"); 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='".$_POST['compName']."'");//quote for post array

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); //Check for total number of rows

if(is_int($num_rows) && $num_rows >0){
 while($rowval = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $complainer = $rowval['username'];
        $department = $rowval['department'];
        $phonenumber = $rowval['phone_number'];
    }   
  }
else { echo 'No Results were found'; }

mysql_close();
```

Comment: thanks for the code, it really working! but when i try not to search the name, it display "no result were found".

Answer (score 2):

**Few Suggestions:**

- Stop using mysql_* extension, its deprecated and close in PHP 7, use [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).
- try to debug `print_r($_POST)` if need.
- You must need to use IF for ELSE condition.
- When you are using HTML Form input directly in your Query Statement, you need to learn [`mysqli::real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Here is the complete example of your code by using **MYSQLi Object Oriented**:

**Example:**

```
<?php    
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$yourInput = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['compName']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$yourInput'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //your stuff
    }    
} 
else 
{
    echo "no record found";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
include("incls/connector.php"); 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$_POST[compName]'");

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); //Check for total number of rows

if($num_rows){
 while($rowval = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $complainer = $rowval['username'];
        $department = $rowval['department'];
        $phonenumber = $rowval['phone_number'];
    }   
  }
else { echo 'No Results were found'; }

mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in your code. `Else` has no `if`

```
if(count($result)==0){
   echo 'No Results were found';
}
```

Moreover, checkout `sql injection` you are passing in line parameter which can lead to sql injection

Answer (score 1):

please use if for else statement

```
if( $rowval ) {
} else {
   echo "No Rows Found";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the count of records firstly to display the records. Also add the code snippet in a try catch block to track the exceptions without displaying them on UI.

```
try {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$_POST[compName]'");

$count = mysql_num_rows($result); //get the count of rows
if($count > 0)
  {
        while($rowval = mysql_fetch_array($result))
       {
        $complainer = $rowval['username'];
        $department = $rowval['department'];
        $phonenumber = $rowval['phone_number'];
       }
   }    
   else
   {
        echo 'No Results were found';
   }    
    mysql_close();  // Missing semicolon in your code
} catch (e){
   print_r("Error while getting the results.");
}
?>
```